# How to get all rows of np 2d array until a certain vector

Tags: arrays, numpy, slice

Lets say i have a 2d array like this:

```
>>> s
array([[1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 0, 0]])
```

(each row is a one hot encoding of some feature). I'd like to take all the rows of s UNTIL a particular vector is seen. For example, if I want to get all rows until `([0, 0, 0, 1])`, I would like to get:

```
>>> desired
array([[1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0]])
```

Is there a good way to do this in numpy or theano? I've had trouble finding solutions on the online docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Approach #1**

Get the equality against the array you are looking for giving us a `2D` array. Then, look for all row-matching ones with `.all(axis=1)` which would be a `1D` boolean array. Finally, to get the first instance among the matches, use `.argmax()` and slice the array along the rows from start until that index.

Thus, the complete implementation would be -

```
s[:(s == [0,0,0,1]).all(1).argmax()]
```

Sample step-by-step run -

```
In [39]: s  # Input array
Out[39]: 
array([[1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 0, 0]])

In [33]: s == [0,0,0,1] # compare against search array
Out[33]: 
array([[False,  True,  True, False],
       [ True,  True, False, False],
       [ True,  True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True,  True],
       [ True, False,  True, False]], dtype=bool)

In [34]: (s == [0,0,0,1]).all(1)
Out[34]: array([False, False,  True,  True, False], dtype=bool)

In [37]: (s == [0,0,0,1]).all(1).argmax()
Out[37]: 2

In [38]: s[:(s == [0,0,0,1]).all(1).argmax()]
Out[38]: 
array([[1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0]])
```

---

**Approach #2**

Since we are dealing with one-hot encoded array, we could use `argmax` along each row of `2D` input array, thus reducing it to a `1D` array. Similarly reduce the search array to a scalar and rest of the steps stay the same. this would be for memory efficient as we would avoid creating a `2D` boolean array. Let's dive into a sample run directly -

```
In [89]: s.argmax(1)
Out[89]: array([0, 2, 3, 3, 1])

In [90]: np.argmax([0,0,0,1])
Out[90]: 3

In [91]: s.argmax(1) == np.argmax([0,0,0,1])
Out[91]: array([False, False,  True,  True, False], dtype=bool)

In [92]: (s.argmax(1) == np.argmax([0,0,0,1])).argmax()
Out[92]: 2

# Final code
In [93]: s[:(s.argmax(1) == np.argmax([0,0,0,1])).argmax()]
Out[93]: 
array([[1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0]])
```

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you so much!